# taking pull from dev and feature branch in master

Tags: git, version-control

I have a `master` branch and a `dev` branch, now I am trying to work on a feature and for that, I have taken a branch `feature_name` from dev branch.

Now suppose while one of my team is working on `feature_name`, the other team which is still on dev branch made some bug fixes/some new development in the code and added that code by taking pull from `dev` in `master`. Now my master and dev has this new change which my feature_name branch don't have.

Now after completing my `feature_branch` work I decided to take pull from `feature_branch` to `dev` and then from `dev` to `master`.

Can anyone please tell me how can I make sure that `dev/master` has updated code(feature code as well as hot fixes/code added in dev)

Comment: see the changes with  git log --graph --decorate

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I would normally start with a merge from `dev` into `feature_branch` and do proper testing. This will make sure all the changes in `dev` (and also in `master` if they are in sync) are integrated and tested with my feature branch. Then you can merge your branch back into `dev`, which should be a fast-forward merge if no-one else pushed changes to `dev` before you.

If you merged `feature_branch` directly into `dev`, and `dev` into `master`, the result should be identical to what I am describing above. My suggested steps just give you a chance to test properly before pushing the merges.